# Trying to create a Find and replace loop in custom QT creator text editor. I seem to be unable to set the cursor position

Tags: c++, qt, replace, find, qtextedit

So I have this find a replace loop in my custom QT text editor that I am creating. I started with this.

```
while(ui->textEdit->find(findString, QTextDocument::FindFlag()))
        {
            ui->textEdit->find(findString, QTextDocument::FindFlag());
            ui->textEdit->textCursor().insertText(replaceString);
        }
```

This worked, but for some reason it did not seem to work if matches for "findString" were consecutive. For example, if my "findString" was "=" and I had a "==" in the document, this loop would only replace one of the "=" and not both. To remedy this, I thought a good solution would be to change the cursor position to the beginning of the QTextEdit at the end or beginning of the loop. So I have tried this.

```
while(ui->textEdit->find(findString, QTextDocument::FindFlag()))
    {
        //ui->textEdit->textCursor().movePosition(QTextCursor().Start, QTextCursor().MoveAnchor);
        ui->textEdit->find(findString, QTextDocument::FindFlag());
        ui->textEdit->textCursor().insertText(replaceString);
        ui->textEdit->cursor().setPos(0,0);
    }
```

The commented out line in the beginning and the line at the bottom of the loop where both tried to move the cursor position. Neither seems to be working for some reason. Both lines compile just fine though. As a test, I have both lines outside of the loop to move the cursor to the beginning of the document after the loop is ran, but it does not seem that either one of these lines moves the cursor at all. My cursor is always at the last instance of "findString."

I am not sure how to either...

1.Fix my loop so that I do not need to move the cursor.

or

2.Succesfully move the cursor to the beginning of the QTextEdit at the end or beginning of the loop.

Thank you in advance for any insights that you may have to my questions.

Comment: I don't think your initial code works as expected!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just fix the loop this way:

```
while(ui->textEdit->find(findString))
{
  ui->textEdit->textCursor().insertText(replaceString);
}
```

In your first code snipplet, you're calling `find` twice before replacing text, so the first match will always be skipped (never replaced).

If you're developing a "replace all" solution, you may want to move the cursor at the beginning, before the loop:

```
ui->textEdit->moveCursor(QTextCursor::Start);
```

Comment: You solved both of my problems. I was thinking that the instance of "ui->textEdit->find(findString)" in the if statement criteria was just there for the Boolean logic. I didn't think that it was actually calling it twice. Works perfectly. I added a line of your "moveCursor" code before and after the loop so that it will work on the entire text document every time. I might put that as an option in the find/replace dialog though (whether the user wants to find/replace the entire document, or just from where they are to the end.